# Binding base class object to Gridview itemSource in windows store app( metro app) c++ not working

Tags: visual-c++, gridview, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my windows store app i implement the property change event in a base class named "BaseClass" and write the properties which i want to bind to my gridview item and i inherit the this base class "BaseClass" in Derived class "DerivedClass".

```
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
ref class BaseClass: Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}

ref class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
}
```

then i created a Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::IBindableObservableVector^ vector and append base class object from derived class object using safe_cast. But its not binding the base class data to grid view but when i create an object of base class its can bind the data to gridview.

```
DerivedClass^ derivedClass = ref new DerivedClass();
BaseClass^ baseClass = safe_cast<BaseClass^>(derivedClass);

Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::IBindableObservableVector^ m_Vector = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<BaseClass^>();
m_Vector->Append(baseClass);

gridview->ItemsSource = m_Vector; // Not binding data to gridview.
```

but

```
BaseClass^ baseClass2 = ref new BaseClass();
Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::IBindableObservableVector^ m_Vector = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<BaseClass^>();
m_Vector->Append(baseClass2);

gridview->ItemsSource = m_Vector; // its Binding data to gridview.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to annotate your view model as [bindable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindableattribute.aspx):

```
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
ref class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{

}
```

Comment: I edited my post for your clarity. I already added BindableAttribute in and implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my base class. But you mentioned i must added BindableAttribute in my derived class too. I did this but its not working. If you want to see my real implementated code i can share with your. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are your properties public? Maybe they'd need to be virtual or something?

Comment: Yes my properties are public. I give you my implemented file in below link.

This is my derived class(cpp file and header file)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGWDFKOVhqelNLMXM/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGYzVMSEpUVzBoXzA/edit?usp=sharing

This is my base class(cpp file and header file)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGcTlqT0ZGQlA1WkU/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGWjZjNFhyVkpaaEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry i uploaded the wrong file base class file is ok now i am giving you derived class(AddRequest Class) file(header file and cpp file) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGMDc3TUxUX3RMOTA/edit?usp=sharing  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ouejxvWWAGR3ozbndvRl91WXM/edit?usp=sharing